# Uninstall, reinstall, lost entire vault, how do I get it back

Tags: fallout-shelter

My game kept glitching. It kept telling me I had dead dwellers in a room. I checked the room and my dweller lost. None were dead. I tried reloading the game, powering off and back on my device, last resort I uninstalled and reinstalled the app. I thought since it was all under my gmail account it would just reload. I had 200 dwellers, all rooms fully upgraded, all dwellers had guns and outfits. I had 3-5 pets, and 5 Mr handy. All dwellers were above level 30, and many SPECIAL stats were maxed out. How do I get my vault back????

Answer (score 3):

Your saved data is not synced to your Google account, it is all stored locally on your device. Uninstalling the game will have cleared out all associated data, including your save file.

The only way you would be able to get it back, would be if you had a backup of your device data that you could restore.

Comment: When I set the checkbox "Sync with iCloud", it says Error.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get your savegame back is if you had your game saved as "cloud Save". If you didn't checked the cloud checkbox (as seen on the image) the savegame is only stored in your phone. So if you unistalled the game, it will be deleted as well.

[image: Cloud Save]

If you previously saved the game as "Cloud Save", you need to create a new game in the same slot as your previous game was and check the "Cloud Save" option. A popup will come out telling you that there is a conflict and it will ask you if you want to keep the new game or to restore the previous one.